# How would a ruling monarch introduce themselves?

Tags: monarchy

In most situations, a king or queen making a formal public appearance would have someone there to announce or "introduce" them. But what happens if a ruling monarch found themselves without anyone to act as herald, and needed to formally introduce themselves? *(Note: this question is not specific to the British monarchy; I'm asking if in **any** monarchy situation, there is a known precedent or procedure for this.)*

Would, *for example*, Queen Elizabeth introduce herself as "I am Her Royal Majesty* Elizabeth II, by the Grace of God, of Great Britain, Ireland and the British Dominions beyond the Seas Queen, Defender of the Faith"?

Or is there some other convention for monarchs introducing themselves? Does it depend on the situation, such as who they're making introductions to (e.g., heads of state vs common folk, etc)?

Alternately, is it assumed that the ruling monarch will never need to introduce themselves, and therefore no monarchy has a precedent or procedure for it?

*("*Her* Royal Majesty" sounds strange here, because by strict grammar conventions it should be "*My* Royal Majesty", but that sounds even weirder.)

Comment: Does Her Majesty really need an introduction?  I mean, if you're expecting to meet Her Majesty, you'll surely recognise her when you see her?

Comment: When would a monarch ever be alone like this?

Comment: Possibly related https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we, I'm not sure to what extent the royal we was used in English though.

Comment: I believe that is how QE would *formally* introduce herself, if she had to do so, just the way a doctor might say something like: "I'm John Smith, Chair of Pediatrics at Mercy Hospital".  Formal introductions always sound a little odd because they are formulaic; they need to get pertinent information across in the fewest words possible. Oh, and 'Her' in *Her Royal Majesty* isn't a typical possessive. It's an indicative statement — "She who has royal majesty" — and it's not unusual for the powerful to refer to themselves in the third person to establish their greatness as an objective fact.

Comment: Doesn't happen.  The queen doesn't introduce herself.  You are introduced to the queen.  Especially she doesn't formally introduce herself.  So not answerable., voting to close

Comment: @JamesK I'm surprised you'd consider voting to close rather than making that an answer. The question is about monarchy in general, and if the truth is "This doesn't happen and therefore there is no precedent/no official way to do it", that's a valid answer.

Comment: @jamesk if that’s a rule of etiquette or custom, not just something that happens because she’s rich and famous, then I think that would be a perfect answer to this question

Comment: @holy_schmitt Is there any reigning monarch who still uses the Plurales Majestatis? Queen Elizabeth II [does not](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II_of_the_United_Kingdom), for example.

Comment: Nitpicks: (1) It's "[Her Majesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_Majesty)", not "Her Royal Majesty". (2) The full title in the question mentioning Dominions, etc, was changed [in 1953](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/39873/supplement/3023); it's now "Elizabeth II, by the Grace of God, of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of Her other Realms and Territories Queen, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no formal protocol for this, because it just does not happen that a monarch ever ends up in a situation where they need to introduce themselves.

When a monarch appears in a public setting, then they will always be accompanies by a cohort who will take care of formally introducing them whenever they enter the room.

When you have the privilege of meeting the monarch in a private setting, then you are expected to know who they are. If you are not, then you can assume that someone will explain to you how to address the monarch before they lead you to them.

So if you ever run into a monarch and ask them "Sorry, who are you again?", then that's a major faux pas on your behalf, as you were expected to know. Someone of the monarchs cohort will then save the monarch from the humiliation of having to introduce themselves and tell you who you are meeting right now.